# How can i parse json arrays with C++?

Tags: c++, json, boost

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "{ \"values\": \"A\": 1, \"B\": 10 }";
```

I'd like to make this stream into this format below.

```
{
  "values": [
    { "A": 1, "B": 10 }
    ...
  ]
}
```

Does anybody know how to parse the values of array using c++ and boost ptree?

Comment: What have you tried?  For example, did you try calling `read_json`?  If so, what went wrong?  If not, why not?

Comment: Where is the SSCCE that shows your problem?  For now: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+JSON+array+ this has been asked many times and is described in the~20 lines of documentation for the JSON parser

Comment: Read the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Assume input [input.json](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13074957/)

### Using Boost Spirit V2.x

Here's a simplistic method using Boost Spirit Qi:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b098fc1134b16d2)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_match.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

namespace {
    using Element = std::map<std::string, int>;
    struct Array : std::vector<Element> { };

    std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Array& into) {
        using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
        using it = boost::spirit::istream_iterator;

        rule<it, std::string()> s;
        rule<it, Element(), space_type> r, e;

        s = '"' >> ~char_('"') >> '"';
        r = (s >> ':' >> int_) % ',';
        e = '{' >> r >> '}';

        return is >> phrase_match('{'
                    >> lit("\"values\"") >> ':' >> '[' >> (e % ',') >> ']'
                >> '}', space, into);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream ifs("input.json");
    ifs.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

    Array array;
    if (ifs >> array) {
        std::cout << "Parsed " << array.size() << " elements:\n";

        for (auto& e : array) {
            std::cout << "\n--------------------\n{ ";
            for (auto& kv : e)
                std::cout << "\"" << kv.first << "\": " << kv.second << ", ";
            std::cout << " }\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
std::istream& {anonymous}::operator>>(std::istream&, {anonymous}::Array&)
Parsed 13 elements:
--------------------
{ "A": 1, "B": 10,  }
--------------------
{ "C": 3, "D": 12,  }
--------------------
{ "E": 5, "F": 14,  }
--------------------
{ "G": 7, "H": 16,  }
--------------------
{ "I": 9, "J": 18,  }
--------------------
{ "K": 11, "L": 20,  }
--------------------
{ "M": 13, "N": 22,  }
--------------------
{ "O": 15, "P": 24,  }
--------------------
{ "Q": 17, "R": 26,  }
--------------------
{ "S": 19, "T": 28,  }
--------------------
{ "U": 21, "V": 30,  }
--------------------
{ "W": 23, "X": 32,  }
--------------------
{ "Y": 25, "Z": 34,  }
```

### Using Spirit X3

Same deal:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1842c500b66b117)</kbd>**

```
namespace {
    using Element = std::map<std::string, int>;
    struct Array : std::vector<Element> { };

    namespace parser {
        using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
        rule<struct rule_key_t, std::string> s;
        rule<struct rule_element_t, Element> r;
        rule<struct rule_braced_t, Element>  e;

        auto s_def = '"' >> ~char_('"') >> '"';
        auto r_def = (s >> ':' >> int_) % ',';
        auto e_def = '{' >> r >> '}';

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(s,r,e)
    }

    std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Array& into) {
        using namespace parser;

        boost::spirit::istream_iterator f(is), l;

        if (!phrase_parse(f, l, '{'
                    >> lit("\"values\"") >> ':' >> '[' >> (e % ',') >> ']'
                >> '}', space, into))
        {
            is.setstate(is.rdstate() | std::ios::failbit);
        }

        return is;
    }
}
```

Same output with same `main()`

### Using Property Tree

This is somewhat difference, I opted to not implement `operator>>` because Boost Property doesn't really afford that.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2661cbbef19daf1c)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

namespace {
    using Element = std::map<std::string, int>;
    struct Array : std::vector<Element> { };

    Array read(std::string fname) {
        std::ifstream ifs(fname);
        Array into;

        using namespace boost::property_tree;
        ptree pt;
        read_json(ifs, pt);

        for (auto& entry : pt.get_child("values")) {
            Element e;
            for (auto& property : entry.second)
                e[property.first] = property.second.get_value(0);
            into.push_back(std::move(e));
        }

        return into;
    }
}

int main() {
    try {
        auto array = read("input.json");
        std::cout << "Parsed " << array.size() << " elements:\n";

        for (auto& e : array) {
            std::cout << "--------------------\n{ ";
            for (auto& kv : e)
                std::cout << "\"" << kv.first << "\": " << kv.second << ", ";
            std::cout << " }\n";
        }
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
    }
}
```

Of course, the output is, again, the same as earlier.

Comment: And I've completed 3 competing implementation in the grand old tradition of over-kill answers: [live coding session](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/json-arrays-spirit-v2x3-and-property-tree/) ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))

Comment: I do dis to lern @Columbo

Comment: In all seriousness, keep it up, great stuff!

Comment: Boost is strong... very strong. With your few lines I solved my problem that I had for hours... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using [ThorsSerizlier](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer) and the same input as sehe.

Assume input [input.json](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13074957/)

```
#include "ThorSerialize/JsonThor.h"
#include "ThorSerialize/SerUtil.h"
#include "ThorSerialize/Traits.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

struct Data
{
    std::vector<std::map<std::string, int>>     values; // The values input
};
ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(Data, values);  // Describes what can be serialized
                                     // There is a definition for all standard
                                     // types in SerUtil.h

int main()
{
    std::ifstream   dataStream("input.json");
    Data            data;

    // Automatically reads data into C++ structure.
    // Directly from a stream.
    dataStream >> ThorsAnvil::Serialize::jsonImport(data);

    // Converts a C++ structure into JSON for output to  a stream.
    std::cout << ThorsAnvil::Serialize::jsonExport(data);
}
```